# Most quick way to read paper written in Geman

Tags: usage

I am a student majored in mathematics, and need to understand a paper written in German. The only foreign language I learnt is English. I am wondering is there any way to understand this paper more efficient?

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficiently"? I mean, either you speak German or you don't. If you don't, that's what I conclude from your question, you will need to either learn German or find a translation/translator.

Comment: Welcome. There are a pair of mathematicians around. But the question is way to vague. What do you expect, concretely?

Comment: I thought math was always so precise. Shouldn't you understand the whole thing just from looking at the formulas? ;-P

Comment: I knew a German professor at university who could read Russian mathematical papers without speaking Russian. :-) (Contemporary) maths papers are the same in any language; you need to look up the technical terms, then you can follow the reasoning (and work out the missing parts for yourself). Lots of formulas help. You'll pickup the usual phrases and filler words quickly. So a dictionary for mathematical terms (or alternatively, smart use of Google and Wikipedia) is the most important thing,

Comment: @dirkt is absolutely right. I can read mathematics in Portuguese  without having spent one second learning the language. Same for Swedish, Norwegian, Romanian mathematical texts but with  more difficulty. Of course these are languages closely related to languages I *have* studied and this ability definitely stops at  extra-terrestrial languages like Hungarian :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to understand the entire paper, I am afraid the easiest way is to have somebody who speaks German very well with the necessary mathematical background translate it for you. Mathematical texts in German tend to make use of many advanced language features and thus require quite some expertise in syntax, grammar and mathematical vocabulary.

Moreover, in the likely case that your paper is more than 50 years old, there is the additional problem that mathematical didactics (and thus language) has evolved considerably in that time and thus even a native speaker has to deal with a combination of unusual vocabulary and notation. (This comes from experience. The same problem exists in English, so if yo ever read some old English mathematical literature, you should know what I mean.)

If, on the other hand, you only require a specific information from the paper (e.g., was a certain statement made), then there might be other ways, depending on what exactly you need and how much the paper relies on formulas.